# What does "stick a bulls-eye on your back" mean?

Tags: american-english, phrase-meaning

What does this mean?

> It's too bright up there, you might as well stick a bulls-eye on your back.

From the movie [*Judgment Night*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0107286/?ref_=nv_sr_1) (1993).

Answer (score 4):

I don't know the movie, but presumably it means that the character, who is trying to remain hidden, is being told not to go somewhere where they'll be easily seen. To "stick a bulls eye on your back" means to make yourself an easy target.

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://www.subzin.com/search.php?title=Judgment+Night&title_id=M120438ab1&search_sort=Popularity&type=All&pag=49)'s the transcription of the movie.

A `bullseye` is the center of a target in sports such as archery, shooting, and darts. [Reference](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/bullseye)
[image: bullseye]

Those two sentences are from two different people. Based on the several lines that I read from that link, apparently something happens to someone's back (bottom), therefore the other person says: `You might as well stick a bulls-eye on your back`, implying the person's back, so that it can be targeted easier, or that the others can aim their back better!